# How can i fix A column referencing multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have 4 tables:

- `ConditionalOffer` (PK ID, Description,...)
- `UnconditionalOffer` (PK ID, Description,...)
- `Offer` (PK ID,
        Offer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ConditionalOffer.ID,
        Offer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES UnconditionalOffer.ID)
- `Applicant` (ID, Offer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Offer.ID,...)

I know that my codes were wrong at table `Offer` because of a column be cannot referencing multiple tables. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie of SQL and stackoverflow. I will attention the next time. Thank you!

Comment: A column can be included in several FK's.

Comment: Add a tag **now**, to this question, to clarify **what RDBMS** you're using!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column can be part of more than one foreign key constraint, but your syntax isn't correct as you specify the source column twice.

Instead either use inlined constraints like this:

```
create table Offer (
    ID int primary key, 
    Offer int 
       FOREIGN KEY (offer) REFERENCES ConditionalOffer (ID), 
       FOREIGN KEY (offer) REFERENCES UnconditionalOffer (ID)
);
```

Or use explicitly named constraints (which might be cleaner):

```
create table Offer (
    ID int primary key, 
    Offer int,
    constraint fk_cond   FOREIGN KEY (offer) REFERENCES ConditionalOffer (ID), 
    constraint fk_uncond FOREIGN KEY (offer) REFERENCES UnconditionalOffer (ID)
);
```

While this is possible, it does however raise questions about the database design: are the IDs in ConditionalOffer and UnconditionalOffer really the same? How are they kept in sync? Shouldn't those tables be one entity if they share primary key (with the differences refactored to other tables)?

Comment: But when i insert values into `Offer` table, how can it know what choose between Condi or Uncondi table. For example `INSERT INTO OFFER (id, offer) VALUES (1, 2)`

Comment: It can't. Which is a good indication that this design might be flawed. If you have a column that has a foreign key relationship to multiple tables the value you insert would have to exists in all referenced tables and you would have no way of knowing if the Offer was really a ConditionalOffer or an UnconditionalOffer. My guess would be that what you really want is to enforce a rule stating that an Offer must be either one of the types of Offers but not both simultaneously. I'd rethink the database model if I were you.